# data mining BKS gift card liabilities

Tags: bloomberg

Is it possible for me to view a graph of Barnes and Noble's "Gift Card" liabilities over the past few years?

What I've tried is various financial websites that could maybe provide the numbers I'm looking for. For example, Google Finance and Balance Sheet data, Yahoo Finance, Ycharts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: That might be the correct thing to do. There is probably a better stackoverflow for this question...can you show me where? Then I can close the question ASAP

Comment: Maybe there: http://money.stackexchange.com/